# Porting Windows Forms to .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-standard-2.0

Apologies if this is a very naive question. I wrote a Windows Form application using .Net 4.5 sometime ago. Recently, I thought it would be a good idea to port it to a .Net Standard 2.0 application using VS Code.

There were a couple of problems with missing libraries and classes (System.ServiceModel being the biggest gap), but I have got to the point of building the application successfully. However, when I come to run it, I see the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.

Here's the project file if it's useful:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="log4net" Version="2.0.8" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="10.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="3.8.1" />
<PackageReference Include="System.CodeDom" Version="4.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Configuration" Version="2.0.5" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="4.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.3" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.4.0" />
<PackageReference Include="System.Windows.Forms" Version="4.0.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Is there some way to run the application using the System.Windows.Forms library, or should I replace it with a different library for .Net Standard 2.0?

Comment: "Recently, I thought it would be a good idea to port it to a .Net Standard 2.0 application using VS Code." That's only going to be a good idea when Windows Forms is fully supported on Linux and Mac. That is, possibly never, and certainly not any time soon. The .NET Framework isn't going to go away. Applications that are still highly Windows-bound should keep using it. If you're porting for the sake of porting, don't. If you're porting because you really want it to run elsewhere, take a look at Mono.

Comment: Winforms is not available in .net core (which main purpose is cross-platform .net development) and it's quite likely it never will (at least not in near future).

Comment: Incidentally, refactoring code that doesn't have any dependencies on Forms to a .NET Standard library *is* worthwhile. This maximizes the reusability of such code. Standard application code that isn't going to be used elsewhere doesn't benefit (unless, again, you have an actual need to run it on other platforms).

Comment: @Evk: [Never say never again](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/07/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/). :-)

Comment: @Heinzi main. Net core point is cross platform support, and WinForms on .net core 3 will run on windows only, so seems not that much of an improvement to me.

Comment: See my answer on **[System.BadImageFormatException: Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336306/system-badimageformatexception-reference-assemblies-should-not-be-loaded-for-ex/61702386#61702386)**.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot build an application that targets .NET Standard 2.0. Only libraries can target .NET Standard. Applications still have to target a specific runtime - .NET Framework, .NET Core, Xamarin, etc.

Judging by your project file, you're actually targeting .NET Core 2.0.

`System.Windows.Forms` is part of the .NET Framework (and Mono). It does not exist as part of .NET Standard or .NET Core.

Your project file has a `PackageReference` to `System.Windows.Forms`, which will pull in [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Forms) NuGet package. It's unofficial and unlisted. Its very description is "unsupported library".

The DLL inside that package is only a reference assembly, i.e. none of the methods contain any actual code. That assembly only contains definitions.

This is what the error message means by "Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution." The assembly in that package will let you compile, but nothing else.

There is no formal way to run a Windows Forms application on .NET Core (prior to 3.0). There may be a benefit to pulling our your business logic into a .NET Standard assembly, but your user interface will still have to be a .NET Framework application.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - I suspected that this was the case. So, in order to move to .Net standard 2.0, which library do you suggest using for the UI. Is Xamarin.Forms the best choice?

Comment: I think the whole idea is to use .NET Standard for all your logic, while your UI needs to be as "dumb" as possible. That way you can write different UIs for each platform, but reuse the logic across all of them. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceANETCoreLibraryInWinFormsOrNETStandardExplained.aspx

Comment: Don't promise too much.  Porting UI is so hard that they couldn't even make the designer finished for the 3.0 release.  3.1, maybe, big hairy problems.